# Make use of wifi direct without application in a device

Tags: android, wifi-direct

Does anybody know if it is possible to use wifi-direct without an application in android?
Lets say i have a device that makes use of wifi-direct with an application and another device that doesn't have any application for wifi-direct. Is it possible to connect these devices ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What does "connect these devices" mean?

Comment: Ok excuse me. Iam new in all these things and maybe i dont explain it very well. I suppose that it means that these devices could exchange information with wifi direct. I hope it is a quite abstract explanation. Thanks in advance

Comment: I dont know if it is quite clear now.. Maybe we can suppose that one device makes use of the classic demo application for wifi direct. Is it possible to connect these devices if we assume that only one dvice has installed the demo ?